# openGL - failed to display an images

Tags: qt, opengl, opengl-4

Learning to display images using QOpenGLWidget. However, I've met some problems.

1. How can I pass the `GLuint texture` variable (the actual texture loaded from the image) into the shader scripts? Like how to bind `GLuint texture` to `uniform sampler2D texture`? Maybe I am just not realising I already did that.
2. What's the difference between `attribute vec4 vertexColorIn` and `uniform sampler2D texture`? I think the color comes from the texture.
3. Can I use `glTexCoord2f()` and `glVertex2f()` instead of `glVertexAttribPointer()` and `glVertexAttribPointer()`? It's because they seem better to me.

I am still  not clear on the concept about how openGL displays an image, although I've done many researches. I'm not quit sure what I'm doing wrong. The image is **NOT** showing up.

**MyGLWiget.cpp**

shader scipts:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define VS_LOCATION 0
#define FS_LOCATION 1

const char* vertextShader = STR(
    attribute vec4 position;
    attribute vec4 vertexColorIn;
    varying vec4 vertexColorOut;
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = position;
        vertexColorOut = vertexColorIn;
    }
);

const char* fragmentShader = STR(
    varying vec4 vertexColorOut;
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    void main(void)
    {
        ??? = texture2D(???, textureOut).r // no clue how to use it
        gl_FragColor = vertexColorOut;
    }   
);
```

loading an Image texture:

```
void MyGLWiget::loadTexture(const char* file_path)
{
    img_data = SOIL_load_image(file_path, &width, &height, &channels, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data);

    SOIL_free_image_data(img_data);
}
```

initialization:

```
void MyGLWiget::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader::Vertex, vertextShader);
    program.bindAttributeLocation("position", VS_LOCATION);

    program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShader);
    program.bindAttributeLocation("vertexColorIn", FS_LOCATION);

    program.link();
    program.bind();


    static const GLfloat ver[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    static const GLfloat  tex[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glVertexAttribPointer(VS_LOCATION, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, ver);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VS_LOCATION);

    glVertexAttribPointer(FS_LOCATION, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, tex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(FS_LOCATION);

    program.setUniformValue("texture", texture); 
    //texture = program.uniformLocation("texture");
}
```

paintGL:

I'm really confused with this part. I have no idea what should I use to make it to draw an image.

```
void MyGLWiget::paintGL()
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data);
    glUniform1i(texture, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I pass the GLuint texture variable (the actual texture loaded from the image) into the shader scripts? Like how to bind GLuint texture to uniform sampler2D texture? Maybe I am just not realising I already did that.

This binds the texture to texture unit 0:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
```

This is invalid because `texture` is not a uniform location, so remove this line:

```
glUniform1i(texture, 0); // <-- invalid
```

This is invalid too, because the uniform `texture` should be set to the number of the texture unit:

```
program.setUniformValue("texture", texture); // <-- invalid
```

So replace it with:

```
program.setUniformValue("texture", 0); // <-- sampler2D texture uses GL_TEXTURE0
```

Note: I'm assuming here that `setUniformValue` works correctly.

---

> What's the difference between attribute vec4 vertexColorIn and uniform sampler2D texture? I think the color comes from the texture.

`vertexColorIn` comes from the VAO and is different for each vertex. `texture` is the sampler that samples from the texture that's bound to the texture unit that you set above.

In your code you don't need a vertex color, but you do need texture coordinates. So your shaders should look like:

```
const char* vertextShader = STR(
    attribute vec4 position;
    attribute vec4 texcoordIn;
    varying vec4 texcoordOut;
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = position;
        texcoordOut = texcoordIn;
    }
);

const char* fragmentShader = STR(
    varying vec4 texcoordOut;
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texcoordOut);
    }   
);
```

---

> Can I use glTexCoord2f() and glVertex2f() instead of glVertexAttribPointer() and glVertexAttribPointer()? It's because they seem better to me.

`glTexCoord2f` and `glVertex2f` are legacy functions that were removed in OpenGL 3, and are available only in the compatibility profile. You shall not use them.

---

This lines are in the wrong place:

```
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

They shall go after you bound the texture:

```
 glGenTextures(1, &texture);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data);
 // sets the filtering for the bound texture:
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

---

Since the question is tagged [opengl-4](/questions/tagged/opengl-4): you don't need to set any uniforms in this case. You can specify the locations and the bindings directly in the shaders:

```
const char* vertextShader =
    "#version 450 core\n" STR(
    layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
    layout(location = 1) in vec4 texcoordIn;
    layout(location = 0) out vec4 texcoordOut;
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = position;
        texcoordOut = texcoordIn;
    }
);

const char* fragmentShader =
    "#version 450 core\n" STR(
    layout(location = 0) in vec4 texcoord;
    layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D TEX;
    layout(location = 0) out vec4 OUT;
    void main(void)
    {
        OUT = texture(TEX, texcoord);
    }   
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your explaination! But it's still not showing the image. Do I actually need to use `glBindTexture()` twice, one in `loadTexture()` and the other in `paintGL()`?

Comment: @Jinx: There's no harm in doing that. In fact it's better this way because some other code might change the binding between those two calls. However, you shouldn't call `glTexSubImage2D` every time you render the frame, only once you load the texture.

Comment: I know why it wasn't working. I changed `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 1)` to `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)`. Thank you so much, I learnt seomthing. And it won't work without your corretion.

Answer (score 1):

a few edits

```
   const char* vertextShader = STR(
    attribute vec4 position;
    attribute vec4 vertexColorIn;
    varying vec4 vertexColorOut;
    out vec2 TexCoord;//--->add
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = position;
        vertexColorOut = vertexColorIn;
        TexCoord = vec2(aPos.x/2.0+0.5, 0.5-aPos.y/2.0);//a hack,ideally you need to pass the UV coordinates for proper texture mapping.UVs need to be passed in as a uniform or an attribute depending on preference.
    }
);

const char* fragmentShader = STR(
    varying vec4 vertexColorOut;
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    in vec2 TexCoord; //---->add
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_FragColor  = texture2D(texture,TexCoord) //( no clue how to use it) -->here is the change
        //gl_FragColor = vertexColorOut;
    }   
);
```